# How do you save models in Elixir

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I've got a database created using Django models which I'm now accessing using SQLAlchemy and Elixir. The querying works and I can pull items out of the database perfectly happily but when I edit them and try to save them it throws the following exception:

```
>>> p = Problem.query.first()
>>> p
<Problem('Test Problem', 'This is a test problem so the database has something in it', 'SBMT')>
>>> p.name
u'Test Problem'
>>> p.name = "Test_Problem"
>>> p.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elixir/entity.py", line 1116, in save
    return self._global_session.save(self, *args, **kwargs)
    AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'save'
```

What am I doing wrong? Have I missed a crucial part of the set up that is preventing me from saving things to the database or is it a problem with my versions of elixir and SQLAlchemy?

I've already run `setup_all()` and the `metadata.bind` is all set, hence I can query the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no Elixir expert, but from the documentation it looks like it uses something called a global session.

To save the changes to the database, you do a `session.commit()`, there's no `save()` method like in Django.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how I missed that. Somehow I ended up trawling through blog posts and old questions on here involving .save() that never seemed to get anywhere.